# How to program automated shrinkage for a subset of terms in R?

Tags: r, pca, causality, regularization, mgcv

I've got data from a randomized experiment that includes a lot of covariates. I'm interested $\delta$ from a model of the form $y = g(\delta T + X'\beta+ \epsilon)$, where $T$ is randomly assigned and thereby uncorrelated with $X$.  I don't need to include $X$ in the model to get unbiased estimates of $\delta$, but including $X$ will improve statistical precision.  However, $X$ is pretty high-dimensionsal, and its constituents are highly correlated with each other. So including all of $X$ would overly increase degrees of freedom.  Term-wise selection on the other hand is undesirable because factors might look insignificant simply because of multicollinearity.

I was thinking of doing the following:

- Take the principal components of $X$, compute their scores for each
  observaiton, and merge them into my dataset.
- Control for *all* of the
  component scores, as $\tilde X$
- Apply shrinkage to each of the
  $\beta$'s in $\tilde X'\beta$, with separate shrinkage parameters for
  each coefficient in $\beta$

Given that I don't care about any of the coefficients, PCA is fine, and given that they are uncorrelated with $T$, biased shrinkage estimates aren't a problem.  And because PC's are orthogonal, shrinking one won't mess with the others.

The question is how to program it.  Using `mgcv`, I could specify them each as smooth terms with high minimum smoothing parameters (forcing them to be linear), and then using the `select=TRUE` option to add a penalty to the null space of the smoothing penalty.  It'd be something like this:

```
library(mgcv)
m = gam(y~T+s(X1,sp = 1e15,k=3)+s(X2,sp = 1e15,k=3),...,+s(Xn,sp = 1e15,k=3)
,select=TRUE)
```

The drawback there is that I need to spend at least 3 D.F. on each term pre-penalization, which would stop me from including all of my covariates.  After penalization using a framework like the above, I'd expect the dimensionality of X to go down quite a lot.  But `mgcv` can't fit a model with more covariates than data, pre-penalization.

Are there any other approaches that'll do the same thing?

(This is not off-topic, because I'm asking for advice on how to program a particular statistical procedure.  Its not a general programming question.)